# Google Docs Viewer Security

Tags: google-docs

We have an application that enables the user to upload files to our system and view it later on. What we initially did was to convert files that are not PDF to PDF and render it to the client using Iframe, with this implementation our system appears to be slow and takes a few minutes or seconds before it displays to our client, Now this annoys our users since they really don't want to wait for it to Load. Now we are deciding whether to use Google Docs Viewer or not, but would like to proceed with the Idea, but our main concern really with the Service is exposing the files publicly. So are there any security concerns when using the service? Are there any chance to make our files that we view using the services searching in google?

Comment: Any help will do thanks!

Comment: Anyone I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, we are also looking at google doc viewer currently. So I was not able to find any reliable information whatsoever on the security or terms and conditions of this api. Makes me a bit worried. Did you find anything?

Comment: Is free this service in 2021 for comercial or has price link?

Comment: Hi, does any one figures out this question? does Google Docs Viewer exposing the data?